# Why do Windows files moved to Ubuntu NAS disappear?

Tags: windows, files

I have build a Ubuntu NAS to store my windows files. I can move files from windows to the shared folder in ubuntu but when logged in ubuntu, I can't see the windows files that I have moved over to the ubuntu folder. Is there a way to see them from the ubuntu side?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a permissions issue. To check, run the command `sudo ls -la` in a folder that has Windows files. You should see your missing files. (The `sudo` command uses the "super user" account, which has authority to almost everything.)

If so, the problem is that samba is not assigning the correct default permissions to new files. There is a setting in smb.conf that defines the default permissions for new files.

Comment: Thanks for the response but what is the setting that I have to change in smb.conf?

Comment: That depends on what permissions you need. Should a specific group have edit or read rights? Perhaps all users should have edit and read rights? Run "man smb.conf" in a console to get the manual. One possibility is "create mask".

Comment: PS: do the missing files appear when using the sudo command?